# Javafx 8 support mac os monterey?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

While working on textfield, 
I got the following error when inputting and deleting Korean characters.

There was no problem when tested in Big Sur and Catalina.

**it's my develop environment spec**

- java 1.8.0_241
- javaFX 8.8
- gradle 4.5

----------

```java
2022-03-03 16:45:38.794 java[84880:4358497] TSM AdjustCapsLockLEDForKeyTransitionHandling - _ISSetPhysicalKeyboardCapsLockLED Inhibit
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.substring(AbstractStringBuilder.java:933)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.substring(StringBuilder.java:76)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextField$TextFieldContent.get(TextField.java:79)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.getText(TextInputControl.java:454)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.updateContent(TextInputControl.java:564)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(TextInputControl.java:548)
    at javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl.replaceText(TextInputControl.java:510)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextInputControlSkin.handleInputMethodEvent(TextInputControlSkin.java:511)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextInputControlSkin.lambda$new$2(TextInputControlSkin.java:376)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.processInputMethodEvent(Scene.java:2115)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.access$4400(Scene.java:159)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.inputMethodEvent(Scene.java:2511)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$null$7(GlassViewEventHandler.java:627)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleInputMethodEvent$8(GlassViewEventHandler.java:619)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:410)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleInputMethodEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:618)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleInputMethodEvent(View.java:647)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyInputMethod(View.java:972)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyInputMethodMac(MacView.java:135)
```

Comment: Looks more like a general problem JavaFX + Korean input deleting in TextField.

Comment: Java 8 is obsolete. Try to replicate your issue with version 17.0.2+ of  the JRE and JavaFX.  Also note that only 17.0.2+ versions of JavaFX will work with M1 Macs, if that is important for you to support.

Comment: @jewelsea thx~ solved it by setting it to Java 11.